# Random Sample in Excel with Conditional Statement?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of names with data associated with each name (there are multiple items listed for each name).  I am trying to randomly select data for each person to audit.  Right now, the spreadsheet will randomly select data; however, when I sort by name, I find that only half of the individuals have items to audit, while the other half do not.

Is it possible to randomly select x% of the items under each person’s name in Excel?

**Below is a very small sample size as an illustration – actual spreadsheet has 100's of names and thousands of lines of data.**

***I need a formula to randomly select a given % (e.g., 5%)
of "data points" for each "Name".***

```
(Column A)              (Column B)
Name                    Data Point
Sue                      123
Sue                      456
Sue                      789
Brian                    586
Brian                    566
Brian                    949
Brian                    928
Bob                      643
Bob                      235
Bob                      594
```

Comment: As is the only answer we can give is, "Yes, most likely it is possible".  If you would share a mock up of your data and expected output, we could better help.

Comment: This is a mock up of the data on a very, very small scale (name list = 100+ different names, data points = thousands)

Comment: Name Data Point
Sue 123
Sue 456
Sue 789
Sue 156
Sue 125
Sue 4523
Sue 445
Bob 5445
Bob 4536
Bob 45645
Bob 4553
Bob 453
Bob 78
Bob 7868
Bob 456
Bob 694
Bob 1858

Comment: Sorry. New here and I don't know how to include a screen shot

Comment: I need to select a few of the data points for each name. The person named will be responsible for auditing some information associated with each data point. Each person should be auditing 5% of their "data points"

Comment: You will need to [edit] your question and add a link to the photo.  Or you can put raw text in the original question and someone with enough rep will help format it correctly.

Comment: Could you provide a sample picture or file about your problem?

Comment: @L.White,, you need to show us how many names you need every time you want to audit,, I mean to say what is/are the criteria to get name along with data to audit since  you have many. Even if think for RANDOM then any condition for it or it could any !!

Comment: @ Rajesh, for each name, I need to pull 5% of the data.  The amount of data will vary by name. For instance, one person may have 10,000 line items with his/her name, while another person may have only 100 line items (this is an exaggeration for illustrative purposes).  For each person's assigned data, I would like to randomly pull 5% of their data. I don't know how to write macros, but it seems like the first step would be to figure out how to isolate each person's name and set of data. And then run a random function on the individual set of data. Again, all help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @L.White, I can suggest you method will  filter Rows for Name particular while filter Value in said Range. For example Name is `SUE` and Data Point range is between `100` & `500`. This method is better that getting `Randombetween`, just confirm through comments ! ☺

Comment: @Rey Juna: Thank you for your attempt to help, but please don’t replace text with a picture of text.  See [PSA: Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408). It may, under ***rare*** circumstances, be helpful to ***add*** an image that contains (and *illustrates*) text, but please don’t ***delete*** text in order to *replace* it with an image.

Comment: @Blackwood:   See above.

Comment: @Run5k: See above.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using the formula `=rand()`. Adding a random number to each row. Then copy and paste the random number as a value upon itself so it will keep its value permanently. Then you can sort it by the random number leave it for the first X values and delete it for the rest. Then you bring it back in the original order.

To give you more precise instruction I would need a better explanation or a screenshot of your sheet.

Comment: May I ask why my answer was voted down?!

Comment: Can you explain how your suggested answer helps accomplish the OP's goal (to "randomly select data for each person to audit")?

Comment: Not the one who down voted, but answering a vague too broad question with a vague too broad answer is usually seen as a poor answer.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad It already selects the data he wants to make sure that it gets selected for x%. My solution does that but since I don't know how his solution works I can not be more specific to make transfer to a specific example. I'm already out on a limb using the word "row"

Comment: @ScottCraner that's true but my attempt to answer it shouldn't be "punished". At least I don't see a reason why it should be. I would have commented on the question but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: `I would have commented on the question but I don't have enough reputation.` is not a good excuse to put a comment in an answer space.  We all went through that time.  Answer questions that can be answered to gain the point necessary.  Please do not use the answer space for something you even agree should be a comment.

Comment: No my answer is meant as an answer. My comment would have been to ask him to give a more specific example. That has been done. Do I really have to delete my answer especially since it's the only one?!

Comment: That is the whole point, there are no other answers because a specific answer is not possible with the question in its current state.  So there should be no answers.  Answers should be specific examples on how to solve the problem, there is no way an answer can get specific enough to answer this question as we do not know enough to do so.

Comment: Does it explain that anywhere in the guidelines? Intuitively I would argue the other way around: the best possible answer under the circumstances is better then no answer. And also if a view it analytical my: It doesn't do any harm and at least there is the possibility that it helps some one. Or do I overlook s.th.? Also it's strange that only my "unspecific answer" gets downvoted but not the "unspecific question".

Comment: (I wasn't the one who downvoted either -- it didn't occur to me to say so before seeing Scott Scraner's comment) I asked a question meant to guide you in editing your question. The problem as stated is that assigning random numbers and then sorting means not every person in the list has items to audit -- but that's my interpretation and other's will be different. We need more data from L. White.

Comment: I appreciate anyone's assistance with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on (but branching from) [MartinX’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1361982/150988#1361986):

I assume (since you didn’t say otherwise)
that `A` and `B` are the only columns that have data. 
If that’s not true, replace `C` and `D` in the explanation below
with the names of two columns that are available.

- Enter `=RAND()` into cell `C2`
  (I’m assuming that there is exactly one header row,
  and that data begin in Row 2, as shown).
- Enter `=C2>=LARGE(C$2:C$100*(A$2:A$100=A2), CEILING(0.5*COUNTIF(A$2:A$100,A2),1))` into cell `D2`,
  replacing `100` with a number ≥ the number
  of the last row containing data,
  and replacing `0.5` with your *x*% value
  (i.e., *x* ÷100; so, for 5%, use 0.05),
  and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Select cells `C2:D2` and drag/fill down to cover all the rows with data.

Column `D` will now be filled with `TRUE` and `FALSE` values. 
*x*% (rounded up) of the rows for each name will be `TRUE`. 
You can then work directly off this list,
or use it as a basis for conditional formatting, or whatever you want.

**Notes:**

- `RAND()` is a volatile function. 
  Every time you change anything,
  all the `RAND()` values will be reevaluated / recomputed / changed. 
  You can prevent that by turning off automatic Workbook Calculation. 
  It might be simpler to do as MartinX suggested: copy and paste values.
- OK, so Column `C` is filled with random numbers
  between 0.000000 and 1.000000.
- The formula in Column `D`, obviously, is more complicated. 
  I’ll explain it backwards: inside-out, from right to left.

  - `=COUNTIF(A$2:A$100,A2)` counts the rows
    that have the same name as the current row. 
    So, for Rows 2, 3, and 4 (“Sue”), this value is 3. 
    For Rows 5, 6, 7, and 8 (“Brian”), this value is 4. 
    As usual, we use dollar signs (`$`) in `A$2:A$100`
    to indicate that we always want to look at exactly
    that absolute range of cells,
    but we use `A2` without dollar signs to indicate relative addressing,
    i.e., the Column `A` value *in the current row.*
  - `CEILING(0.5*(the_above),1)` gives you *x*%
    (50%, in my example) of the number of people with that name, rounded up. 
    It’s important not to let this value equal 0. 
    If you want to round down in general,
    but still round numbers less than 1.00 up to 1,
    use something like `MAX(INT(0.5*(the_above)),1)`.

    For your given example data (with “Sue” and “Brian”),
    this evaluates to 2 for every row. 
    If you had 831 rows of data for, say, “John”,
    i.e., `COUNTIF(A$2:A$100,A2)` is 831, and *x* is 5
    (i.e., we want to audit 5% = 0.05 of those rows),
    then this value would be 42 for every “John” row
    (0.05*831=41.55, which rounds up to 42).
  - `(A$2:A$100=A2)` creates a virtual array
    that is `TRUE` in the positions corresponding to the rows
    that have the same name as the current row, and `FALSE` otherwise. 
    So, if we look at Row 2 (or 3 or 4),
    this virtual array will look like {T, T, T, F, F, F, F, F, F, F}.
  - `C$2:C$100*(A$2:A$100=A2)` extends the virtual array
    from the previous step
    by multiplying it by the random numbers in Column `C`. 
    In a mathematical context, `TRUE` equals 1 and FALSE equals 0. 
    So, if the random numbers in Column `C`
    are {0.83, 0.17 ,0.60, 0.42, 0.95, …},
    then this virtual array will look like {0.83, 0.17, 0.60, 0, 0, …},
    i.e., the random numbers corresponding to the current person,
    and zeroes for everybody else.
  - So `LARGE(C$2:C$100*(A$2:A$100=A2), CEILING(0.5*COUNTIF(A$2:A$100,A2),1))`
    is `LARGE((virtual_array_of_selected_random_numbers), N)`,
    where *`N`* is *x*% of the number of people with the current name. 
    This gives the *`N`*th largest number in that array. 
    So, with your given example data (with “Sue”, etc.)
    and my hypothetical numbers (above),
    this would be 0.60 for “Sue”
    (the 2nd largest number in the array 0.83, 0.17, 0.60, 0, 0, …).
  - `=C2>=LARGE((that_mess))` evaluates
    whether the random number in the current row is greater than or equal to
    the *`N`*th largest random number for the current person. 
    Pretty much by definition,
    this will be true for *`N`* of the rows for the current person.

    The `LARGE` function is the key to getting *x*% of the items
    under each person’s name, as requested by the question. 
    Following up on the above example, if you had 831 rows of data for “John”,
    and *x* is 5 (i.e., we want to audit 5% = 0.05 of those rows),
    then `CEILING(0.05*COUNTIF(A$2:A$100,A2),1)` would be 42 for John,
    and `LARGE(…, 42)` is the 42nd largest number. 
    So `C2>=(that_number)` is true
    for the largest 42 numbers (but see the next paragraph);
    i.e., it is `TRUE` for 42 rows. 
    Thus, this Boolean expression is TRUE on 5% of the 831 rows for “John”. 
    I.e., this automates the step that is done manually in MartinX’s answer.

    It is theoretically possible that two random numbers will be equal. 
    For example, Sue’s numbers might be 0.83, 0.17 and 0.17.
    Then the 2nd largest of those (`LARGE({those_numbers},2)`)
    would be 0.17, and so it would be true for 3 rows. 
    (I.e., you’ll get one more `TRUE` than you want.) 
    This will happen ***very*** rarely.
- We need to enter the formula in cell `D2`
  with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
  to make it an “array formula”,
  which is necessary to work with virtual arrays.

Here’s an example outcome:

[image: sample results]

(I added a row for myself to demonstrate that
(at least) one row will be selected for each person
(even if that row gets a very low random number).)

Comment: Nice idea but it doesn't give him the necessary x% "positives" as he requested. Unless I overlooked s.th?!

Comment: I believe that you must be overlooking or misunderstanding something. I can’t identify what it is, because you don’t explain your critique. Did you overlook my statements that I was using *x* = 50 for demonstration purposes, and that I was rounding up? There are 3 Sues, 4 Brians, and 3 Bobs (and 1 Scott).  50% × 3 = 1.5 → 2, 50% × 4 = 2, and 50% × 1 = 0.5 → 1. In my example, 2 of the Sues, 2 of the Brians, 2 of the Bobs, and the 1 Scott are selected. Why do you believe that this is not what the OP wanted?

Comment: @MartinX: Hello? I upvoted your answer (I was the only person who did so; it has two downvotes) because I thought it had a germ of a good idea, even though I believe that it is incomplete (it doesn’t really explain how the OP can use it to solve the problem).  Please explain your objection to my answer.  (And, if you can’t articulate a problem with my answer, the decent thing to do would be to upvote it.)

Comment: sorry wasnt online Formular a while.i didn't see where you amount for the x% positives. But it should be in the ceiling part of the formula ?! I think I have to try it out...

Comment: @MartinX:  I edited my answer, expanding on the explanation.